# How to debug git remote set-url not working

Tags: git, github

I'm unable to change git remote url from `git://` to `https://`.

As illustrated below, `git remote set-url` isn't working:

`$ git remote -v`

> > origin git://github.com/userName/repoName.git (fetch)
> >
> > origin git://github.com/userName/repoName.git (push)

`$ git remote set-url origin https://github.com/userName/repoName.git`

`$ git remote -v`

> > origin git://github.com/userName/repoName.git (fetch)
> >
> > origin git://github.com/userName/repoName.git (push)

I have also tried removing the remote and re-adding it, to no avail.

**.git/config**

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://github.com/userName/repoName.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

I have checked many of the plethora of queries concerning `git remote set-url`, but none dealing with this issue of `set-url` not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## SOLVED

From running `$ git config --list` I realized that **.git/config** was forcing git to rename all remotes. [See here for more information](https://gist.github.com/taoyuan/bfa3ff87e4b5611b5cbe).

To resolve the issue, you can either:

1. Manually edit the file: `git config --global --edit`
2. Remove section: `git config --global --remove-section url."git://github.com/"`

The second option is preferable as it is safer than directly editing git config file.

Comment: Thank you so much! It took me awhile to realize my origin fetch was set to repo.git instead of the actual repo name. It was because I had a global configuration somehow saved to repo.git that prevented me from changing with set-url.

Answer (score 1):

Use command (You maybe must using Administration permission on Windows operating system, or `sudo` permission on macOS or Linux)

```
git remote add upstream https://example.com/ORIGINAL_OWNER/ORIGINAL_REPOSITORY.git
```

See https://help.github.com/articles/configuring-a-remote-for-a-fork/