# setting remote url not changing to https

Tags: git, git-remote

I am trying to change my remote URL from `git@github.com:BuddyBob/Py_Programs.git`
to `**https://**github.com/user/repo2.git`.

so simply I did

```
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/BuddyBob/Py_Programs.git
```

and

```
git remote -v
```

But it does not seem as anything has changed

```
origin  git@github.com:BuddyBob/Py_Programs.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:BuddyBob/Py_Programs.git (push)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/q/54437545/245915

Comment: did not help me.

Answer (score 2):

Funny enough. I did some digging into my github config.

I realized somewhere in the file I had. Which could be the cause of my problem.

```
[url "git@github.com:"]
      insteadOf = https://github.com/
```

So I switched them around.
And what do you know!

I simply run

```
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/BuddyBob/Py_Programs.git
```

and

```
git remote -v
```

I get

```
origin  https://github.com/BuddyBob/Py_Programs.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/BuddyBob/Py_Programs.git (push)
```